# Using Stored Procedure in PHP to get rank

Tags: php, wordpress, stored-procedures

I have a store procedure that ranks a leaderboard table. How can I pull the rank of a specific userid from the array? This is the array my procedure dumps when I perform this query:

```
 $userposition = $wpdb->get_results("CALL addrank"); 
 print_r($userposition);
```

Array Output:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 11 [Result] => 69 [Bonus]
>   => 0 [Total] => 69 [Rank] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 32 [Result] => 38 [Bonus] => 0 [Total] => 38 [Rank] => 2 ) [2] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [userid] => 37 [Result] => 38 [Bonus] => 0 [Total]
>   => 38 [Rank] => 2 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 7 [Result] => 38 [Bonus] => 0 [Total] => 38 [Rank] => 2 ) [4] => stdClass Object (
>   [userid] => 19 [Result] => 38 [Bonus] => 0 [Total] => 38 [Rank] => 2 )

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach($userposition as $row):
    echo $row['userid']." -> ".$row['Rank']."<br>";
endforeach;
?>
```